# How to place a Market link inside an App?

Tags: java, android

In my app I want to have something like "Click HERE"  where 'HERE' is a link to the app in the market.

So I've done:

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appbrain);
            link.setText("market://details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=pt_PT");
            Linkify.addLinks(link, Linkify.ALL);
```

But this does not work. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, both answers are partially right; the problem of both is that links are not clickable. However, I found the problem.

When we want to linkify URLs (directly) we just have to do:

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
        link.setText("http://google.pt");
        Linkify.addLinks(link, Linkify.ALL);
```

But when we want to "play" with the link we need to use (as stated in another answer) we could use HTML:

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appbrain);
            link.setText(Html.fromHtml("" +
                    "- Download <a href=\"https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps\">Appbrain</a>" +
                    " to update all your apps!"));
```

Even if we use the following code, the link will not be clickable.

```
Linkify.addLinks(link, Linkify.ALL);
```

The solution is just using the following code:

```
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the web version of the link:  `http://market.android.com/details?id=<package name>`.  Users will either be prompted whether they wish to open the link in the Browser or Market app, or if they have already chosen a default it will open right away.

You could also use some HTML and set the text of the TextView like this:

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"market://details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=pt_PT\">CLICK HERE</a>"));`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to define a pattern, as this URL is the custom defined for the market application.

```
 Pattern appWordMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]+[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+\\b");
 String appMarketURL = "market://details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=pt_PT";
 Linkify.addLinks(txtView, appWordMatcher, appMarketURL);
```

For more information see [WikiNotes: Linkify your Text!](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html)

Comment: Probably for the same reason than the other answer, it's not working. Link appears, but is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just make a button or clickable textfield and launch an activity from there.

```
  try
  {
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.mypackage.myapp")));
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot load Play Store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```